# Super-efficient way to report on whether or not there are fiction books costing more than $10

Tags: xml, performance, xslt, xslt-2.0, processing-efficiency

My XML document consists of a series of Book elements of various genres (fiction, non-fiction, etc.)

I want to create an XSLT template that outputs `true` if:

1. There are no fiction Books.
2. There are fiction Books and each costs less than or equal to $10.00

I want the template to output `false` if:

3. There are fiction Books that cost greater than $10.00

My template below does the job, but I am hoping you can provide a more efficient solution. My template takes a lot of steps to solve such a simple problem. I suspect that my template would have poor performance with a large set of data. Can you provide a super-efficient solution to the problem?

Here's my template:

```
<xsl:template match="Books">
    <xsl:variable name="fiction-books" select="Book[Genre eq 'Fiction']" />
    <xsl:variable name="no-fiction-books-that-cost-more-than-10-dollars" select="not(exists(Book[Genre eq 'Fiction'][number(Cost) gt 10.00]))" />
    <xsl:variable name="no-fiction-books" select="not(exists($fiction-books))" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$no-fiction-books or $no-fiction-books-that-cost-more-than-10-dollars" />
</xsl:template>
```

Here's a sample input (the XSLT should output `false` with this input):

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>ABC</Title>
        <Genre>Fiction</Genre>
        <Cost>10.00</Cost>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Title>DEF</Title>
        <Genre>Fiction</Genre>
        <Cost>20.00</Cost>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: According to your second point, given input is will give 'true', because one book's cost is **less than or equal to 10**.

Comment: It's very likely that the cost of this simple transformation will be dominated by the cost of launching the XSLT transformation engine, compiling the stylesheet, and parsing the source document. So improving your XSLT code may be a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the template to output false if:
>
> 3. There are fiction Books that cost greater than $10.00

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="/Books">
    <xsl:value-of select="not(Book[Genre='Fiction']/Cost >10)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the output is not XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

`<xsl:value-of select="count(Book[Genre='Fiction'][Cost &gt; 10]) = 0" />`

This counts all books where the `Genre` is **'Fiction'** and the `Cost` is greater than **'10'**.  It then checks if that count is equal to 0.